# Old Grub need to be restored?

Tags: grub2

I'm dual booting Precise with Windows and wanna make the switch to Quantal, should I  set the bootloader again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do.

I assume this is not a WUBI install.

1. If you want to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 using the **update manager,**
   nothing needs to be done regarding GRUB.
2. If you **upgrade using installation DVD/USB,** GRUB may get installed
   again. In that case, make sure it installs in its previous location,
   most likely to be at `sda`.
3. If you want to do a **fresh install,** overwriting 12.04, GRUB should be
   installed in the same location it was previously installed. Most
   likely to be at `sda`.

Hope this helps

Comment: What you described as step 3 fits perfectly for me, thank you.